# How to code if else statement with odd numbers

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement, excel-formula

I don't know how to do this in if else statement

I want to to write IF the user input is odd number THEN Msgbox "Not valid" ELSE solve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That'll be:

```
If Value Mod 2 Then 
    MsgBox "Not valid."
Else
    ' Solve.
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

when it comes to odd and even we use the mod which gives us the remainder, if the remainder is 0 the number is even and if it's 1 then it's odd hope this helps:)